# How to Debug Tests in React Native When Using Jest and Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I'm trying to setup some debugging for the tests in my app I'm building with React native on expo. I followed some instructions from online resources. Below are the settings from my package.json. When I run a test with this script `node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand`
I see the break point hit in the chrome dev tools and on continuing I see some warnings on the console  but not much else.

I'm not even sure what am I supposed to see. Would there be some output even when there is no error? Just in case I deliberately made an error in the test and still nothing on the console. May be it is because of those warnings?

Package.json

```
 "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to open chrome://inspect in Chrome, you should be on the Devices tab, then click Open dedicated DevTools for Node

It also helps to put debugger; in your source where you want it to break.

[Chrome Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBTzZ.png)

Comment: I'll add that you probably want to profile a subset of your tests, otherwise your profile will be too large and I've had Chrome crash because of that. So follow the script with a file or folder name to only profile those tests. Additionally, make sure the tests are not run in watch mode.